# When Cyrillic characters in ajax response encoding is wrong

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the fallowing Cyrillic string i want to return in my ajax response : 'Този еmail е вече регистриран'.

How ever when i do this:

```
<?php
    public function echoCyrllic(){
        $json['error']='Този еmail е вече регистриран';
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
 ?>
```

My response is this:

```
{"error":"\u0422\u043e\u0437\u0438 \u0435mail \u0435 \u0432\u0435\u0447\u0435 \u0440\u0435\u0433\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0440\u0430\u043d"}
```

Can anybody help. Thanks.

Comment: This is becoming a very often repeated question - that's not wrong it's simply encoded

Comment: [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyGPe/) might help you understand that this is how a correct JSON looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this json is valid... even though it looks dirty.. the json will decode it correctly

try it out

```
 alert(reponse.error);
```

if in case you don't want as such then.. send `error` as text and use condition to display this where you wanted..

like

```
 $json['error']='error';
 echo json_encode($json);
```

and in javascript

```
if(response.error == "error"){
     alert('Този еmail е вече регистриран');
}
```

**however, this is just another way to do it.. but i prefer to go with the first one.. since there is nothing wrong with the first one..** :)

Comment: yep, it is correct... nvm... the moment when you spend 40 minutes correcting something that is correct... priceless

Comment: haha :).. i  know... anyways happy coding.. :)...